# Saving file from online path in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to save file via C# in asp.net from the given path

```
 FileUpload fileToUpload =new FileUpload();
 string path = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.08326024943277,74.79841209948063&zoom=21&size=550x450&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true";
 string FileName = "mirImg" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 fileToUpload.SaveAs("~/saveImages/" + FileName);
```

Comment: Yes - and? Does it not work? Do you get an error? If so: **what is** that error?

Comment: i think i need to create fileUpload Control first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the data as bytes and then write to a file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.08326024943277,74.79841209948063&zoom=21&size=550x450&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true");
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\file.jpg", data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile(path, FileName);
}
```